# Standard for storing email messages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, encryption, mailgun

I'm using the MailGun Routes functionality on Google App Engine (Python) to process incoming emails. I am basically first storing all values that MailGun provides (reference here: http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#routes) and then use this to initiate additional processes.

This all works fine, however I am thinking it might not be good practice to have the actual content of the messages in readable form in the database. Is this an accepted practice? And are there any standards I could look into which I could implement to improve the privacy level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no specific standards for email privacy. There is a [house bill](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/1852) but this is not legislation and even then may not apply to you.

As you are using emails as a trigger for some other action (essentially as a job queue, if I understand your application correctly) once the action is completed, you can discard the email and just log the type of action done.

I am sure there are instances where emails are stored in databases both for the application side (aka, hotmail/gmail) and for later parsing and analysis (for NLP or other purposes).

The first case (storing for application use by end user), email is just like any other data that you need to protect with appropriate restrictions and controls - there is nothing special about it.

In the second case, normally the content is sanitize and personally identifiable information removed (mainly, the headers) and the text content is searched in aggregate.

You'll have to take a decision based on the nature of your application what constitutes legitimate use of the data.

Comment: Thanks Burhan. I need to store the content of the messages as well, so I guess it comes closest to hotmail/gmail in terms of what you describe. In terms of restrictions and controls I think everything is in order, I am just thinking if I should encrypt the messages, and if so, what encryption to use.

Comment: Controls are a direct result of risk. So ask yourself what is the risk?